# How to change order status to paid after the offline payment was selected?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sylius

Using stable Sylius `1.2.0`, how one can mark the order as paid after the offline payment method was selected?

Tried using an after-callback of the `sylius_order_payment` state-machine`, but it doesn't seem to fire on any transition:

```
winzou_state_machine:
    sylius_order_payment:
        callbacks:
            after:
                set_order_paid:
                    on: ['complete']
                    do: ['@AppBundle\Payment\StateMachine\Callback\CallbackClass', 'updateOrder']
                    args: ['object']
```

Is the state machine used at all? Maybe I'm using the wrong one. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your patience.

**Update 1**

Tomorrow I'm going to try the [Completing a Payment with a state machine transition](http://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/book/orders/orders.html#completing-a-payment-with-a-state-machine-transition) chapter from the documentation. I'm thinking about putting this code inside an event listener listening on *Order created resource event*, albeit the state machine callback sounds like a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally made it working:

`state_machine.yml`:

```
winzou_state_machine:
    sylius_order_checkout:
        callbacks:
            after:
                app_order_complete_set_paid:
                    on: ['complete']
                    do: ['@AppBundle\Order\StateMachine\Callback\OrderCompleteSetPaidCallback', 'setPaid']
                    args: ['object']

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    AppBundle\Order\StateMachine\Callback\OrderCompleteSetPaidCallback: ~
```

`OrderCompleteSetPaidCallback.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Order\StateMachine\Callback;

use SM\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use AppBundle\Infrastructure\CommandBus\CommandBus;
use AppBundle\Order\SetPaid\SetPaidCommand;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\OrderInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Payment\PaymentTransitions;

final class OrderCompleteSetPaidCallback
{
    private $stateMachineFactory;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $stateMachineFactory)
    {
        $this->stateMachineFactory = $stateMachineFactory;
    }

    public function setPaid(OrderInterface $order): void
    {
        if (!($lastPayment = $order->getLastPayment())) {
            return;
        }

        if ('cash_on_delivery' === $lastPayment->getMethod()->getCode()) {
            $this->transition($order);
        }
    }

    private function transition(OrderInterface $order): void
    {
        $stateMachine = $this->stateMachineFactory->get($order, OrderPaymentTransitions::GRAPH);
        $stateMachine->apply(OrderPaymentTransitions::TRANSITION_PAY);

        $payment = $order->getLastPayment();

        $stateMachine = $this->stateMachineFactory->get($payment, PaymentTransitions::GRAPH);
        $stateMachine->apply(PaymentTransitions::TRANSITION_COMPLETE);
    }
}
```